# Saying l'shem mitzvas tzitzis in bathroom

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, tzitzis, bathroom, tying-knots-kosheir

Can one say l'shem mitzvas tiztzis in a bathroom? I was thinking of a case of tying the knots or fixing it. Since tiztzis is not a davar shebikedusha maybe it should be fine, or maybe since its mitzva related we want don't want you to think Torah thoughts in a bathroom.

Comment: [We follow lots of Halachot in the bathroom.](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x343)

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4491

Answer (score -2):

The body of the garment that the tzitzit are attached to is not a davar shebekedusha, but the strings are very much so. In fact, the most mehadrin of strings are spun with tzitzit making in mind. Tying tzitzit is not a bathroom activity. Also, it is probably something that would be easier to do at a desk.

Comment: [Edit]ing in a source for your claims, and for how they address the asker's question, would improve your answer a lot.