# Why learn either Rambam or Shas?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, rambam, adult-learning, mishneh-torah

Why learn either Rambam or Shas being that we don't *pasken* straight from a Gemara nor do we Ashkenazim from the Rambam? And being that the Rambam says in his introduction that his work (Yad Chazakah) is all the final rulings throughout Shas.

So then what's the point in learning Gemara, Rashi Tosfos when we could just learn just straight from the Rambam?

Alternatively, if there is a benefit in learning Gemara, Rashi, Tosfos all day, is there a point in learning straight Rambam?

Comment: See the Hakadama of the Yam Shel Shlomo

Comment: If possible, wanna send me a link? @sam

Comment: Post here please! #wanttoseeittoo

Comment: It's in hakdama in Chullin, will send later

Comment: Who said we don't pasken straight from a Gemara or from the Rambam?

Comment: Oh my. That's an excellent question that I'm quite sure we've answered in a few other questions. I'm just uncertain which is the best to refer you to. Brief answer - it's always best to study the source of all information, when you can. I think you understand that concept. All Ramba"m and Shulchan Aruch do is "cut to the chase" and tell you what to do. That's great if that's all you want to know. But, in most cases, I'd like to know why or "how do we know?" That's where learning Gemara and Tanac"h comes in. Incidentally, Gemara frequently provides a Torah or Tanac"h source as well. Makes sense

Comment: It's known. Unless you can tell me/proof me otherwise @Alex

Comment: @sam I just looked over the Yam Shel Shlomo's Hakdama In B"K, it's the same thing as Chullins. Great stuff. Thank you. Very informative.

Comment: @Moshe The responsa that I read frequently draw conclusions directly from a Gemara or Rambam. See e.g. the responsum cited in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99705/13438).

Comment: @Alex First off, I'm not saying Reputable Poskim don't bring proofs from The Rambam or the Gemara for a grey area question. What I'm saying is that, any Talmid Chochum/Layman/Rasha or other, don't open up a Rambam/Gemara and say, "This is the conclusion so I'm gunna do this"... Rather, they open up a M'B/A'S/K'SA/Other Contemporary Halacha seforim and they derive the Halacha from there. This isn't a question as to why learn Gemara if it's not Halacha. I'm asking why learn Gemara when I can learn it all in Gemara. Now "Sam" gave a great source to look an answer and now my problems solved". TY.

Comment: @Moshe consider posting a full answer with the information you gained from Sam's comment. Will be super helpful for others.

Comment: https://www.mishnetorah.co.il/why-maimonides_en/

Answer (score 1):

[Why we learn *gemara* has been extensively covered on MiYodeya, e.g., [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45399/11501), [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40929/11501) and [there]](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40916/11501).

One of the goals of learning is to know the entire Torah (*kol ha Torah kula*) (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69136/11501) on MY for sources whether or not it is an obligation or simply a worthy practice). Since the Torah is infinitely broad and deep, this is impossible, but learning [Mishne Torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishneh_Torah) is one way to approach it.

As you know, the Rambam codifies all *halachot*, both those practiced today and those that will be practiced when the *Beit Hamikdash* is rebuilt. As such, it is broader than most traditional halachic codes (e.g., Shulchan Aruch, Kitzur SA). The language of the Mishne Torah is also exceptionally clear and structured; its organization makes it easier to remember what is where.

It is for these reasons the last Lubavitcher Rebbe instituted a [daily learning schedule](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/900030/jewish/Learning-Daily-Rambam-Mishneh-Torah.htm) for Mishne Torah

> It gathers all of Jewish law in a concise and clear fashion. Every
>   individual is commanded to study the entire Torah, a goal not within
>   reach for most people. However, it is possible to study the whole
>   Torah as compiled by Maimonides.

To get to practical *halacha*, I note that recent editions of the Mishne Torah (e.g., [Koren](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/talmud/mishna/rambam-mishneh-torah-set.html)'s from R Steinsaltz, or R Touger's available [online](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah.htm) in English) bring rulings from Shulchan Aruch and other *aharonim* where they differ from the Rambam.