# Saying brocho in modern restroom

Tags: blessing, bathroom, mishnah-berurah

I've been going through the *Mishna Berura* on saying *shma* in restrooms (מ״ב סימנים פ״א-פ״ז so far) and I'm rather curious what the *halacha* is relating to modern restrooms. ([This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/praying-in-a-restroom) only discussed restrooms generally). The entire discussion seems to revolve around (a) odor and (b) the visible presence of feces. For this question please assume there is **no odor** in the room, as that significantly simplifies things.

Lets break this into two use cases:

- **Residential restrooms** – Modern restrooms with indoor plumbing removes the vast majority of the feces immediately, with minimal to no residue. Additionally, nearly all residential toilets come with a cover that can immediately cover up any remaining feces.
- **Public restrooms** (the clean ones) – The actual toilets are in their own cubicles and use high-powered flushing mechanisms to remove nearly all waste, again with minimal to no residue.

MB פ״ז:א:א-ו discusses whether one can say *shma* near a chamber pot (I believe) and seems to suggest (פ״ז:א:א) that the only issue is the smell. The *Shulchan Aruch* in פז:ב suggests that "*yesh osrim v'yesh matirim v'halacha k'divrei ha osrim*", but the MB mainly points out (פ״ז:ב:ח) that the smell is the issue. For public restrooms, there's a discussion which I didn't entirely follow in the following *se'if* on cubicles, which seems to hinge on whether they reach the ground, which may make entire classes of restrooms OK for saying a *brocho* when near the sinks...? This is particularly relevant for people using the restrooms for something other than relieving oneself (e.g., taking drink of water, only washing *netilas yadayim*, etc).

Curious to hear what modern *poskim* have suggested about this.

Comment: Rabbi Y.P. Feinhandler told me he was of the opinion that if a room only has a toilet in it then the room has a *halacha* of a toilet, however if you have a bathroom with a toilet, sink and bath then the room does not have the *halacha* of a toilet.

Comment: Modern restrooms with indoor plumbing removes the vast majority of the feces immediately. Not really I think the old trains which poskim do talk about somewhere went straight onto the track.

Comment: @eykanal Thanks for writing up the question in such a clear, well-informed manner! This is a valuable dupe.